# Access denied finding property "net.dns1" on Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, agora.io

I am using agora video call on my app and getting bellow errors on Android physical devices and emulators. There is no any problem on iOS yet. So I believe it's not about app_id is not correct.

here is error:

```
D/agora-jni( 4883): android bridge create done...
E/libc    ( 4883): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc    ( 4883): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
E/libc    ( 4883): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc    ( 4883): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
```

this is my app/build.gradle file:

```
...

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

   ...

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.4.0-alpha02'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am using r8 shrink and proguard. My proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class io.agora.**{*;}
```

And my gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```

My pubspec.yaml file:

```
permission_handler: ^6.1.1
agora_rtc_engine: ^3.1.3
```

Comment: Does this error prevent you from using Agora? I have had this error as well, but Agora worked successfully for me.

Comment: @cjacky475 my app routes to video_call_page.dart and showing these errors on terminal. there is no any image or screen error or connection message in video call page.

Comment: This error won't cause any behavior difference on Agora service. There must be another problem that caused this issue. Could you please debug and see if you are joining the channel successfully and get the remote user's id from the onUserJoined() callback?

Comment: @ShaochengYang Thank you for your comment. I debugged it and deleted "close camera option". It's working well now. I had put the camera off button but I removed it. But still I don't understand why it just failed on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `Access denied finding property "net.dns"` shown on logs is just a warning as mentioned on this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/issues/41#issuecomment-624979308) and shouldn't cause issues running the app. What you can do here is check if there's a different cause of the issue. See if you're able to get the user id if you're able to join a channel successfully.